# Change v$session machine

Tags: database, oracle

there!

Actually, I've been trying to set v$session machine field. The reason is about containers. We're working with a pod that enable oracle db connection, the session sets pod's name within machine, but when pod dies the next session's machine changes.

We apply a validation over every log in to db. We use the machine field to allow interaction with tables, views, etc.

So, we need to set into machine something like: app-1.apps.openshift.com. That's the container's hostname, so if pod dies, the machine field won't change and It will continue with flow quietly.

Someone knows How to set session's machine?

I tried from oracle driver with golang & python, but I don't get the results I want.

I hope you can help me.

With love, Bran. <3

Comment: It is not possible to modify that information through the Oracle Client as far as I know; you would need to set every pod name to be the same and let the Client software read it normally. Using v$session fields is not considered wise for connection filtering as they may change frequently, and with more specific programming skills (not using Oracle Client) most can be spoofed by a malicious actor to overcome such filters. In your case an attacker need only change the hostname of their client. They are more appropriately used for auditing and general monitoring.

Comment: What are you using this column for? maybe a better solution exists than using v$session.machine which I don't think you can modify programmatically.

Comment: We already had this discussion on https://github.com/godror/godror/issues/240 (where I did ask for more info... feel free to add it).  You'll have to use a driver that supports faking these values, e.g. JDBC.  Oracle's C client stack (used by godror, cx_Oracle, and the Thick mode of python-oracledb) doesn't.  Neither does the Thin mode of python-oracledb.  I don't know whether Oracle's ODP.NET managed driver supports it.